# SQL Replication Automatically Add table to Publisher

Tags: sql-server, database-design, replication, transactional-replication

I am using SQL 2012 transactional replication for an entire database. Everytime I add a new table, say Table A, I have to manually go to the SSMS GUI, and add the table to be publisher, then I resync to import data.

Is there a way to automatically add tables with data into replication, or do I have to write a dynamic/t-sql/powershell script, which checks if sys.tables is replicated and then automatically adds to replication `sp_addarticle` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbuilt way of automatically adding new table to replication. This means, you have to carve out your own method suited to your environment.

Couple of thing that you should do ..

- Poll sys.tables or have a trigger to fire on `CREATE_TABLE`
- Check if table has primary key (must for replication)
- modify publication property - `immediate_sync` to `0` --> should be done once to avoid generating snapshot for all articles.
- Call sp_addarticle and sp_addsubscription to add article to publication and subscription.
- Kick off snapshot .. this will generate ONLY shapshot for the article that is newly added.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here is a script I just wrote that handles the whole thing.
It adds missing articles to all publications existing on the source DB.
Adjust as needed for your environment, and please provide feedback if you see anything wonky.

```
DECLARE @RowID INT;

/* Table for all existing publications */
DECLARE @Publications TABLE
(
    RowID             INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,PublicationName  sysname
    ,PublicationID    INT
    ,TargetServerName sysname
    ,TargetDB         sysname
);

/* All publications and articles listed */
INSERT INTO @Publications
(
    PublicationName
    ,PublicationID
    ,TargetServerName
    ,TargetDB
)
SELECT  DISTINCT
        p.name AS PublicationName
        ,p.pubid AS PublicationID
        ,s.srvname AS TargetServerName
        ,s.dest_db AS TargetDB
FROM    dbo.syspublications AS p
        INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles AS a ON a.pubid = p.pubid
        INNER JOIN dbo.syssubscriptions AS s ON s.artid = a.artid;

SET @RowID = @@ROWCOUNT;

/* For each publication */
WHILE @RowID > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @WorkingPublicationID     INT
            ,@WorkingPublicationName  sysname
            ,@WorkingTargetServerName sysname
            ,@WorkingTargetDB         sysname
            ,@WorkingSQL              VARCHAR(MAX);

    /* Stores relevant bits about publication */
    SELECT  @WorkingPublicationID = p.PublicationID
            ,@WorkingPublicationName = p.PublicationName
            ,@WorkingTargetServerName = p.TargetServerName
            ,@WorkingTargetDB = p.TargetDB
    FROM    @Publications AS p
    WHERE   p.RowID = @RowID;

    DECLARE @RowID2 INT;

    DECLARE @Articles TABLE
    (
        RowID        INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
        ,TableName   sysname
        ,TableSchema sysname
    );

    /* Gets info for each article in working publication */
    INSERT INTO @Articles
    (
        TableName
        ,TableSchema
    )
    SELECT  t.name
            ,s2.name
    FROM    sys.tables AS t
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s2 ON s2.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT   1
                           FROM     dbo.syspublications AS p
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles AS s ON s.pubid = p.pubid
                                    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t2 ON t2.object_id = s.objid
                                    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s3 ON t2.schema_id = s3.schema_id
                           WHERE    s2.name + '.' + t.name = s3.name + '.' + t2.name
                                    AND p.pubid = @WorkingPublicationID
                       )
            AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0;

    SELECT @RowID2 =  @@ROWCOUNT;

    /* Execute add article to working publication */
    WHILE @RowID2 > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @WorkingArticleName    sysname
                ,@WorkingArticleSchema sysname;

        SELECT  @WorkingArticleName = a.TableName
                ,@WorkingArticleSchema = a.TableSchema
        FROM    @Articles AS a
        WHERE   a.RowID = @RowID2;

        EXEC sys.sp_addarticle @publication = @WorkingPublicationName
                               ,@article = @WorkingArticleName
                               ,@source_owner = @WorkingArticleSchema
                               ,@source_object = @WorkingArticleName
                               ,@force_invalidate_snapshot = 1
                               ,@destination_table = @WorkingArticleName
                               ,@destination_owner = @WorkingArticleSchema;

        SET @RowID2 = @RowID2 - 1;
    END;

    /* after articles are added, refresh subscription */
    EXEC sys.sp_refreshsubscriptions @publication = @WorkingPublicationName;

    SET @RowID = @RowID - 1;
END;
```